# magento - shipping to multiple addresses but keeping payment to one charge

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to find a way to allow an order to be split for multiple shipping addresses, but to keep the charge to the customer as a one time payment rather than having to charge for each shipment separately. Is there a way to do this? Currently, customers are getting charged multiple times, corresponding to their "multiple orders", as magento splits the orders up into many smaller ones. This is a problem from the credit card company side since they are getting suspicious of so many consecutive charges to the card.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not going to be able to provide a full solution because to be honest, the solution would take quite a bit of time and testing but I'll give out comprehensive information that could you to the right direction instead.

Basically, upfront -- there isn't an option to do this in default Magento.

So instead, we are going to rewrite a certain model called `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping`. If you're into the proper way of rewriting a model, please read [this post by Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/).

But if you're lazy and looking into a quick way of rewriting, then please copy the whole file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php`

Once you've finished either of the two above, you can move on to rewriting stuff we need into this class. Check out the function around `line 498`:

```
public function createOrders()
{
    $orderIds = array();
    $this->_validate();
    $shippingAddresses = $this->getQuote()->getAllShippingAddresses();
    $orders = array();

    if ($this->getQuote()->hasVirtualItems()) {
        $shippingAddresses[] = $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    }

    try {
        foreach ($shippingAddresses as $address) {
            $order = $this->_prepareOrder($address);

            $orders[] = $order;
        ....
        } 

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $order->place();
            $order->save();
       ...
    }

    ....

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_submit_all_after', array('orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $this->getQuote()));

        return $this;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_multishipping_refund_all', array('orders' => $orders));
        throw $e;
    }
 }
```

So we can clearly see here that it's trying to create an order for each address and then (the most important part), triggering the `checkout_submit_all_after` event which is monitored by the payment modules (order and quote information are passed to all of the available/active payment modules and the payment method set inside the quote will determine if a certain payment module receiving the dispatched event can process it or not).

With that in mind, you can have a couple of options now:

1.) if you can live with just one order, then try and rewrite the `createOrders` routine to just combine all items again into one order, `->place()` it, then pass into dispatchEvent for good measure.

2.) if you need multiple orders, well -- this is where it becomes convoluted as there's a slim chance that you can do either of the following:

- create a payment first then link it into the orders (almost impossible to do)
- create the orders *and* another 'combined' order in which you will pass into the dispatchEvent. sounds filthy and/or wrong so don't bother maybe?

So yeah, you guys are pretty much asking for a lot here so the best I can do is to shed some light on where you can first do serious damage. I'd do it myself, but it's above my pay-grade here.

Some additional pointers:

- Watch out for the session methods right after order creation, know where they lead too
- Also be wary of all the dispatched events. They all have a purpose why they are there and where they are.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this option is enabled:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, when customer clicks one page checkout button, ship to multiple adresses option wouldn't be shown to him. But if he clicks on main checkout button it would.

Comment: the thing is that I want customer to be able to checkout with multiple addresses. The question is about how magento processes payment - essentially what it does is split the order into a number of ones, according to how many addresses the goods are being shipped to. Each of these orders in turn get billed separately. I want the customer to get only one charge on his credit card for the one order he made, shipped to multiple addresses.

Comment: Want the same as @helefa any advice?

Comment: doesn't answer the question